# Hash table Chain puttall()

Tags: java

I am working with a java hash table chain (an array sorted by the hascode of the key's value where the indices are linked list's). Here is the initialization of the hash table for the test code:

```
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashtableChain<String, Integer>();

    myMap.put( "ACTG", 120 );
    myMap.put( "ABC", 123 );
    myMap.put( "XYZ", 123 );
    myMap.put( "HTML", 404 );
    myMap.put( "LOL", 999 );
    myMap.put( "OMG", 911 );

    Map<String, Integer> otherMap = 
                          new HashtableChain<String, Integer>();
    otherMap.put( "ARC", 121 );
    otherMap.put( "ACT", 102 );
    otherMap.put( "AUT", 109 );
    myMap.putAll( otherMap );
    System.out.println( "myMap pairs:" );
    System.out.println( myMap );
```

This is what it's supposed to output:

```
myMap pairs:
[[OMG=911][LOL=999], [ARC=121], [AUT=109, ABC=123], [AUT=109, ABC=123], [ACTG=120], [XYZ=123], [CIT=245], [HTML=404], [ACT=102], ]
```

With this method:

```
public void putAll( Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map ){
Iterator<? extends K> nextKey = map.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator<? extends V> nextValue = map.values().iterator();
    while(nextKey.hasNext() && nextValue.hasNext()){
        put((K)nextKey.next(), (V)nextValue.next());
    }
}
```

Methods used in the method above:

```
public Set<K> keySet(){
    Set<K> coll = new HashSet<K>();
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
        if(table[i] != null){
            for(Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[i]){
                coll.add(nextItem.key);
            }
        }
    }
    return coll;
}
public Collection<V> values(){
    Collection<V> coll = new LinkedList<V>();
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
        if(table[i] != null){
            for(Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[i]){
                if(nextItem.value != null){
                    coll.add(nextItem.value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return coll;
}
```

This outputs:

```
[[OMG=911][LOL=999], [ARC=109], [AUT=102, ABC=123], [AUT=102, ABC=123], [ACTG=120], [XYZ=123], [CIT=245], [HTML=404], [ACT=121], ]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is a different way to do it. All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this :

```
Iterator<? extends K> nextKey = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(nextKey.hasNext()){
        put((K)nextKey.next(), map.get(nextKey.next()));
    }
```

Comment: Nearly worked, instead of: 
put((K)nextKey.next(), map.get(nextKey.next()));

I did:
K key = nextKey.next();
put(key, map.get(key));
 Because it was giving me a null pointer(value being one step ahead of key). Can't believe I over looked the get() function in the first place... too many hours starring at the same code I guess...

Answer (score 1):

This is working off of G V's code(didn't want to edit his/hers without consent).

```
Iterator<? extends K> nextKey = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(nextKey.hasNext()){
        K key = nextKey.next();
        put(key, map.get(key));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `putAll` method is buggy because there's no requirement that the `keySet()` and `values()` be matched. Instead use [`Map#entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) to retrieve them as matched pairs.

Comment: I was having trouble because when trying to use dot notation on map I couldn't access the .table that stored all of the keys and values and didn't realize that I had completely forgotten about the map.get(Key) function that returns a value based on the key.